# Make a Loop for daily windspeed in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, loop

This code give me mask out pixels where in all of wind speeds are below 5, but if I want use this code for many days what should I do? It is hard to write for 30 days. Actually, I want run this code for 01/01/2020 to 30/01/2020.

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
  .filter('wld_rgn == "SE Asia"')

var Windspeed = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01'))
  .select('Wind_f_inst')
  .mean()

var Windspeed1 = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-02'))
  .select('Wind_f_inst')
  .mean()
  
var Windspeed2 = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-03'))
  .select('Wind_f_inst')
  .mean()  

var Windspeed3 = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-04'))
  .select('Wind_f_inst')
  .mean() 
  
var Windspeed4 = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-05'))
  .select('Wind_f_inst')
  .mean() 
  
var mask = Windspeed.gt(5).or(Windspeed1.gt(5)).or(Windspeed2.gt(5)).or(Windspeed3.gt(5)).or(Windspeed4.gt(5))

var u = Windspeed.updateMask(mask)
var u1 = Windspeed1.updateMask(mask)
var u2 = Windspeed2.updateMask(mask)
var u3 = Windspeed3.updateMask(mask)
var u4 = Windspeed4.updateMask(mask)

var windt = u.add(u1).add(u2).add(u3).add(u4)

var WindVis = {
  min: 46.05683272577041,
  max: 101.32877871485076,
  palette: ['1303ff', '42fff6', 'f3ff40', 'ff5d0f'],
}


Map.addLayer(windt.clip(fc), WindVis,'U2')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what your problem is. You have in January of 2020, for 'NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H' each 3 hours product, 248 images and you need one image for each day (total 31 images because January has 31 days; not 30). To make a Loop for daily mean wind speed in Google Earth Engine, you can use the following code for entire dates range (2020-01-01, 2020-02-01). It masks all daily images in that range for values lesser than 5 and clip them for your fc area. It also prints only the first image of that dates range because I don't know what do you want to do with this series.

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
  .filter('wld_rgn == "SE Asia"');

Map.centerObject(ee.Geometry.Point (104.359, 16.095), 7);

var windSpeed = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01', '2020-02-01'))
  .select('Wind_f_inst');

print(windSpeed);

var startDate = ee.Date('2020-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-02-01');

var days = endDate.difference(startDate, 'days');
var daysStep = 1;

function masked (img) {
  
  var mask = img.gt(5);
  
  return img.updateMask(mask).clip(fc);
  
}

var newWindSpeed = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, days.subtract(1), daysStep)
    .map(function (offsetDays) {
      var start = startDate.advance(offsetDays, 'days');
      var end = start.advance(daysStep, 'days');
      var composite = windSpeed  // former lst
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .mean();
      return composite.set('system:time_start', start.millis());
    })
  ).map(masked);

print(newWindSpeed);

var WindVis = {
  min: 5,
  max: 10,
  palette: ['1303ff', '42fff6', 'f3ff40', 'ff5d0f'],
};

Map.addLayer(newWindSpeed.first(), WindVis,'U2');
```

After running above code, result looks as follows (centered in 104.359, 16.095 point, zoom 7). All observed pixels in Laos, Thailand, Vietnam and Cambodia have values greater than 5 m/s.

[image]